# Can I make a method which takes an instance and returns map object as static?

Tags: java

apologizes if I ask a dumb question. I have a method which takes an object, converts it into a map and returns the map object. It does not access any instance variable of the class in which it is declared.

logger is again a static field.

```
public Map<String, Object> createDocumentMap(final DocId docId) {

        logger.debug("Creating document map...");
        Map<String, Object> documentMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        documentMap.put("docNumber", docId.getDocNo());
        documentMap.put("docRev", docId.getDocRev());

        logger.debug("Document map ready. " + documentMap);

        return documentMap;
    }
```

I don't know whether to declare it as static or not despite reading many thread about static method vs non-static method.

Comment: Short answer : yes, you can. Did you try? Just declare the method as `public static Map<String, Object> crea..`.

Comment: Declare method static or not depends on your requirement If you declare method as static then you can call this method by using class name else you have to call this method via instance veriable.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Is there any harm if this static method again calls another static method?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya No :) And in that case, it would be a bad practice if this method was not static.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Yeah you are right. The other method is also static. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how will you use this method. If you use it only within an instance it should stay instance method. 
Since this method doesn't depend on any instance variable you can change it to static. Do it in case if you will use this method from another objects. In this case you  can also consider moving this method to some utility class.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not depend on any instance variables (fields) or methods then you can. Otherwise you can't.

In practice `static` methods are often used in general purpose utility classes which does not depend on context only parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your method is using instance variable, so you can not make a method static that using instance variable/object.

Comment: I mentioned the method does not use any instance variable of the class in which it is declared

Answer (score 0):

Declare the map in the class as a static property.

```
public static Map<String, Object> documentMap = null;
```

and initialize it in your method.

```
documentMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Comment: Soo..you make a static public variable which is not final (can be null) and you assign reference to it in a public non-static method (making it void?!). You could hardly make it any worse.